# PostgreSQL - Slow Count

Tags: postgresql

I need to write one time query. It will be run one time, and the data will be moved to other system (AWS Personalize). It does not need to be optimized for sure, but at least sped up a bit, so the migration of data is even possible.

Coming from MySQL I thought it would not be a problem. But reading a lot, it seems the COUNT function is handled differently in PostgreSQL. Having mentioned all of that this is the query, reduced in size. There are several other joins (removed from this example), but they do not present an issue, at least looking at the QUERY PLAN.

```
explain
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id)
    'plan_progress' AS EVENT_TYPE,
    '-1' AS EVENT_VALUE,
    extract(EPOCH FROM p.created_at) AS CREATION_TIMESTAMP
FROM plans p
    INNER JOIN schedules sch ON p.id = sch.plan_id
WHERE p.status = 'ENDED' AND p.continuous IS NOT TRUE
   AND (select Count(id) FROM schedules s WHERE s.plan_id = sch.plan_id AND s.status = 'DONE') = 1
```

The issue is here:

```
select Count(id) FROM schedules s WHERE s.plan_id = sch.plan_id AND s.status = 'DONE'
```

The id field in the schedules table is uuid.

I have tried lots of things, but they all end up the same. Same or worse.
I have read somewhere it is possible to use row estimate in these cases, but I have honestly no idea how to do that in this case.

This is the query plan:

```
Unique  (cost=0.99..25152516038.36 rows=100054 width=88)   
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..25152515788.22 rows=100054 width=88)
        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_schedules_plan_id_done_date on schedules sch  (cost=0.56..25152152785.84 rows=107641 width=16)
              Filter: ((SubPlan 1) = 1)
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Aggregate  (cost=1168.28..1168.29 rows=1 width=8)
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on schedules s  (cost=14.78..1168.13 rows=58 width=16)
                            Recheck Cond: (plan_id = sch.plan_id)
                            Filter: ((status)::text = 'DONE'::text)
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_schedules_plan_id_done_date  (cost=0.00..14.77 rows=294 width=0)
                                  Index Cond: (plan_id = sch.plan_id)
        ->  Index Scan using plans_pkey on plans p  (cost=0.42..3.37 rows=1 width=24)
              Index Cond: (id = sch.plan_id)
              Filter: ((continuous IS NOT TRUE) AND ((status)::text = 'ENDED'::text))
```

Comment: I would need exact count. I just checked, and there is index on schedules.id

Comment: Your query would benefit from an index on `schedules(plan_id, status)` so try adding that.

Comment: Is the reason for the `distinct on ()` that your JOIN returns multiple matches? If yes, rewriting that JOIN to an `exists` condition would also help as you can then get rid of the `distinct on ()` (and the needed `order by` for it)

Comment: Yes. I need distinct on, so it does not return multiple matches.

Comment: But the multiple matches supposedly result from the JOIN (assuming `plan.id` is the primary key) which doesn't seem necessary as you don't need any columns from the `schedules` table.

Comment: Correct, I do not need any rows returned from the schedules, only the number.

Comment: Could you show us the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) _your_sql_ ? Otherwise we can only guess what's going on

Comment: I think the join can be removed completely. If there is exactly one schedule with status `DONE` it would be included in the join, so it doesn't add anything to the logic. I think you can simplify it tom something like this: https://pastebin.com/EzzfFW9i  (but that would still require an index on `schedules (plan_id, status)`

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have included the query plan in the first post.

Comment: @Wexoni: the plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers) select ...` would have been more interesting.

Comment: Why are you counting `id` specifically tho? Can you have null ids and you want to exclude them? Because otherwise you should *really* `count(*)`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am trying to run it with explain(analyze, buffers), but it runs already for a 6 mins without results.

Comment: As a first step you should add that index on `schedules (plan_id, status)` or maybe even `schedules (plan_id) where status = 'DONE'`

Comment: I am going to do that, and see if it speeds up.

Comment: I'll vote to close. Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, this is guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

- you are not selecting any column from the `schedules` table, so it can be omitted from the main query, and put into an `EXISTS()` term
- `distinct` is probaly not needed, assuming `id` is a PK
- Maybe you dont need the `COUNT()` to be exactly one, but just `> 0`

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id)
    'plan_progress' AS EVENT_TYPE
    , '-1' AS EVENT_VALUE
    , extract(EPOCH FROM p.created_at) AS CREATION_TIMESTAMP
FROM plans p
WHERE p.status = 'ENDED' AND p.continuous IS NOT TRUE
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM schedules sch  
        WHERE p.id = sch.plan_id
        )
AND EXISTS(
        select *
        FROM schedules s
        WHERE s.plan_id = p.id
        AND s.status = 'DONE' -- <<-- Must there be EXACTLY ONE schedules record?
        ) ;
```

---

Now you can see that the first `EXISTS()` is actually not needed: if the second one yields `True`, the first `EXISTS()` **must** yield `True`, too

---

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT ON (p.id)
    'plan_progress' AS EVENT_TYPE
    , '-1' AS EVENT_VALUE
    , extract(EPOCH FROM p.created_at) AS CREATION_TIMESTAMP
FROM plans p
WHERE p.status = 'ENDED' AND p.continuous IS NOT TRUE
AND EXISTS(
        select *
        FROM schedules s
        WHERE s.plan_id = p.id
        AND s.status = 'DONE' 
        ) ;
```